# Sticky item staying relative to the parent

Tags: html, css, sass, sticky

I have a sticky sidebar that I'm trying to keep inside parent class. That is staying inside the `.inner` box.

Currently, it is overflowing into the `.outside` box.

Here is the JSFiddle with an example - https://jsfiddle.net/dky2eb3m/10/

HTML:

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="other">

  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="content">
      One
    </div>
    <div class="content two">
      TWO
    </div>
    <div class="content three">
      Three
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="outside">

</div>
```

SCSS

```css
.content {
  height: 400px;
  background: red;

  &.two {
    background: green;
  }

  &.three {
    background: grey;
  }
}

.other {
  height: 300px;
  background: yellow;
}

.parent {
  //overflow: hidden;
}

nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 25%;
  left: 100%;
  height: 0;

  ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    li {
      list-style: none;
      position: relative;
      background: white;
      width: 80px;
      height: 80px;
      display: block;
      border-radius: 10px;
      color: #f47324;
    }
  }
}

.outside {
  height: 400px;
  background: orange;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want your `nav` to be inside then you can do that like this.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 3000px;
}

.content-parent {
  background: purple;
  width: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
  float: left;
  position: sticky;
  top: 30px;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  /* order: 999; */
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  color: #f47324;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.outside {
  height: 400px;
  background: orange;
}

.content {
  height: 400px;
  background: red;
}
.content.two {
  background: green;
}
.content.three {
  background: grey;
}

.other {
  height: 300px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="content-parent">
    <div class="content">
      One
    </div>
    <div class="content two">
      TWO
    </div>
    <div class="content three">
      Three
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="outside">

</div>
```